# Linux permissions are changing automatically

Tags: linux, permissions

For any reason sometimes the permissions for the folder /home/folder1 changes. How can I know who is changing the permission? or better how can I disable this option for the folder?

Linux distribution
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the audit package to accomplish this task.
- Ensure the auditd service is running, and set to start on boot chkconfig auditd on
- Set a watch on the required file to be monitored by using the auditctl command:

  ```
  auditctl -w /home/folder1 -p war -k monitor-folder1
  ```

That is:

- auditctl: the command used to add entries to the audit database.
- -w: Insert a watch for the file system object at path, i.e. /etc/shadow.
- -p: Set permissions filter for a file system watch. r=read, w=write, x=execute, a=attribute change.
- -k: Set a filter key on an audit rule. The filter key is an arbitrary string of text that can be up to 31 bytes long. It can uniquely identify the audit records produced by a rule.

For Permanent watch  you must add your rule to /etc/audit/audit.rules on RHEL5 or RHEL6 or RHEL7 or Centos 7(or /etc/audit.rules on RHEL4) in order for them to persist after reboot.

For more detail follow the link

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10107

Comment: yes, I tried that, but only can see the follow   
type=CWD msg=audit(1491956709.60):  cwd="/home/testlog01"
type=PATH msg=audit(1491956709.609:425886849): item=0 name="log/status2" inode=70361 dev=fd:02 mode=040777 ouid=1001 ogid=1003 rdev=00:00 objtype=NORMAL
type=CRYPTO_SESSION msg=audit(1491957476.414:425886850): pid=25588 uid=0 auid=0 ses=629 msg='op=start direction=from-server cipher=aes256-ctr ksize=256 mac=hmac-sha2-256 pfs=curve25519-sha256@libssh.org spid=25588 suid=0 rport=3282 laddr=10.13.105.10 lport=22  exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=10.13.105.101 terminal=? res=success'

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL/CENTOS: You can monitor permission changes as below:

Use the `audit` package to accomplish this task.

Ensure the `auditd service` is running, and set to start on `boot chkconfig auditd` on

Set a watch on the required file to be monitored by using the `auditctl` command:

Raw

## `auditctl -w /etc/hosts -p war -k monitor-hosts`

That is:

auditctl: the command used to add entries to the audit database.

**-w**: Insert a watch for the file system object at path, i.e. /etc/shadow.

**-p**: Set permissions filter for a file system watch. r=read, w=write, x=execute, a=attribute change.

**-k**: Set a filter key on an audit rule. The filter key is an arbitrary string of text that can be up to 31 bytes long. It can uniquely identify the audit records produced by a rule.

***Note that you must add your rule to /etc/audit/audit.rules***

Comment: yes, I tried that, but I what are looking for? 

my log is to big because the folder is sharing with smb process